# SDWebImage, Getting url image in indexPath.row

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

I have an issue with SDWebImage, I have a `UICollectionView` and I am trying to get the URL images to `indexPath`.  I am stuck it seems that I missing a key point in the cell. Any help on this. I guess that it is something stupid, but hey.. also to mention I have many URLs image not only one

Here is my struct

```
struct Regions {
let imageName: String
let imageUrl: String
let titleName: String
let action: String
let actionUrl: String

init(imageName: String, imageUrl: String, titleName: String, action: String, actionUrl: String) {

    self.imageName = imageName
    self.imageUrl = imageUrl
    self.titleName = titleName
    self.action = action
    self.actionUrl = actionUrl
}
```

}

my append method

```
    actions.append(Regions(imageName: "agorianicam", imageUrl: "http://agorianicam.forecastweather.gr/agorianicam.jpg",  titleName: "Αγόριανη", action: "agoriani", actionUrl: "http://5.196.92.163:8080/agoriani.html"))
```

`cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! RegionListingCollectionCell

   // cell.imgView.sd_setImageWithURL.image = UIImage.init(named: actions[indexPath.row].imageUrl)
    cell.imgView.image = UIImage.init(named: actions[indexPath.row].imageName)
    cell.titleLabel?.text = actions[indexPath.row].titleName

    return cell

}
```

Comment: yes, but they are many urls over 20 ..  so ..

Comment: But you're showing one on one cell as you're using `collectionView`.

Comment: `cell.imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: actions[indexPath.row].imageUrl), placeholderImage: anyPlaceholderImage)`

Comment: yes each cell with have one url image

Comment: See my last comment that should work for you.

Comment: Thanks, man... It works

Answer (score 0):

Use `cell.imgView.sd_setImage(with: yourUrl, placeholderImage: anyPlaceholderImage)` instead of assigning the image. Or see the [SDWebImage Doc](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for more info.

So according to your code below piece of code should work for you:

```
cell.imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: actions[indexPath.row].imageUrl), placeholderImage: anyPlaceholderImage)
```